# I am getting an error like this 'Invalid input data format for Statevector'

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-gate

I am new at QC. I learn from a course. When I write to this code:

> ```
> from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit
> q = QuantumRegister (1)
> c = ClassicalRegister(1)
> qc = QuantumCircuit(q,c)
> qc.draw('mpl')
>
> from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector
>
> psi1 = Statevector(qc)
>
> psi1.draw('latex')
> ```

I am gettin an error :

```
> QiskitError                               Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-28-eccf64e782f7> in <module>
> ----> 1 psi1 = Statevector(qc)
>       2 psi1.draw('latex')
> 
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\quantum_info\states\statevector.py
> in __init__(self, data, dims)
>      72             self._data = np.ravel(data.data)
>      73         else:
> ---> 74             raise QiskitError("Invalid input data format for Statevector")
>      75         # Check that the input is a numpy vector or column-vector numpy
>      76         # matrix. If it is a column-vector matrix reshape to a vector.
> 
> QiskitError: 'Invalid input data format for Statevector'
```

Can you help me?

thanks your time.

Comment: Does the variable `qc` refer to an instance of `QuantumCircuit`?

Comment: Can you please share the complete code?qc needs to be an instance of a QuantumCircuit.

Comment: I am sorry, I am fixing it now

Comment: This code worked with me with no issues. What version of Qiskit do you have?

Comment: I use jupyter notebook on anaconda. when I install I wrote "pip install qiskit" on CMD.exe of anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tips for you to understand error:

- take a look at qiskit docs, what is the valid data input, learn more about Statevector class
  https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.Statevector.html
- and from output error
  `QiskitError: 'Invalid input data format for Statevector'`
  which mean you didn't input the expected data(np.array or list or Statevector or Operator or QuantumCircuit)
- check sources code if it make sense, and discuss in StackExchange or slack then report bug to github sources code, if there is any bug.

I hope these tips help you though study QC.
also please provide more info about your input for Statevector, if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. I edited my question and I added the complete code. May you help me now? Thanks you again.

Comment: @Oilon it works for me, you can try to reinstall qiskit-terra. or Check the source code, if statement check is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solve my problem. I deleted everything and reinstall it worked.